# Understanding the input_shape parameter of hub.KerasLayer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

When transfer learning is done, one could use a model from the tf hub. Like MobilNetV2 or Inception. These models expects the inputs, the images in a certain size. So one has to resize the images into this size before applying the models. In this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub) the following is used:

```
feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/2" 

feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                         input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

In this example the images were already resized to 224,224 before. I am wondering about the `input_shape=(224,224,3)`. In this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) the pretrained model is not loaded with the hub-KerasLayer, but instead using

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
```

Where IMG_SHAPE is

```
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```

and img_size is 160. So here the input_shape is input_shape=(160,160,3).

Now coming back to the:

```
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                         input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

I was wondering what exactly the input_shape parameter  tells me or does? So I do not need to enter 224,224 here, right? I could enter another size, like 160, because my images were resized to this size? So MobilNetV2 does expect 224,224, but with this option I can specify something else? For `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` I found the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNetV2) where it exactly explains it:

> Optional shape tuple, to be specified if you would like to use a model
> with an input image resolution that is not (224, 224, 3). It should
> have exactly 3 inputs channels (224, 224, 3). You can also omit this
> option if you would like to infer input_shape from an input_tensor. If
> you choose to include both input_tensor and input_shape then
> input_shape will be used if they match, if the shapes do not match
> then we will throw an error. E.g. (160, 160, 3) would be one valid
> value.

So when I resized my images to 300,300 and I want to use MobileNetV2, can I use the following code:

```
 feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/2" 
    
    feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                             input_shape=(300,300,3))
```

Or do I have to resize to 224,224 and enter the 224,224 here?

When I check an [implementation](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l06c03_exercise_flowers_with_transfer_learning_solution.ipynb#scrollTo=wVII2H9ZNNQf) for inception the images are resized to 299,299 and then the following code is used:

```
IMAGE_RES = 299

feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(URL,
  input_shape=(IMAGE_RES, IMAGE_RES, 3),
  trainable=False)
```

Is it necessary to do this exactly to 299? Or could I also resize to another size, like 250 and give this as an input:

```
   IMAGE_RES = 250

feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(URL,
  input_shape=(IMAGE_RES, IMAGE_RES, 3),
  trainable=False)
```

So the pretrained models do expect a certain fixed size and this input_shape parameter exists in order to make it flexible in case the user wants to use another size, right? But then why all these examples resize to exactly the size the models assume? I could also have done this to another size, right? So in all the examples it says like the models expects this and I understand it in the way that therefore we do have to resize to exactly what the model expects. But the input_shape parameter is exactly existing for this to make it flexible so that I do not have to resize to exactly what the model expects, but instead just resize to whatever I want and with the input_shape parameter I tell this to the model? As in the mentioned example with 160 image size. Or is this just possible in case I use `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` loading the pretrained models, but when using `hub.KerasLayer` I cannot do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good observation.

**TLDR**, different `Input Shapes` can be passed for `Models` of `tf.keras.applications` with the argument, `include_top = False` but that is not possible when we use `tf.keras.applications` with the argument, `include_top = True` and when we use `Models` of `Tensorflow Hub`.

**Detailed Explanation**:

This [Tensorflow Hub Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures/images#image_input) states

```
> The height and width dimensions are fixed to the expected size of
> input images. (Future work may remove that restriction for fully
> convolutional modules.)
```

That's the reason, if we pass the `Image Shape` other than the Expected Shape, it raises an error,

```
 Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * True
        * False
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * True
        * True
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * False
        * True
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        * False
        * False
        * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

Similarly, when we pass different `Input Shape` while using the `Pre-Trained Models` of `tf.keras.applications` with the argument, **`include_top = True`** (including the Dense Layers at the Top as well), it raises an error,

```
ValueError: When setting `include_top=True` and loading `imagenet` 
weights, `input_shape` should be (224, 224, 3).
```

But if we set the value of argument, **`include_top = False`** while using the `Pre-Trained Models` from `tf.keras.applications`, the `Input_Shape` can be **flexible** i.e., for MobileNetV2, we can pass any of the shapes from the list, `[96, 128, 160, 192, 224]`) and for Models like `ResNet` or `VGGNet`, we can pass any `Input Shape`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is only 50% true. "But if we use the Pre-Trained Models from tf.keras.applications the Input_Shape can be flexible because it has been handled in the Source Code of those Model." This is not true. It is only possible for image_size for the following values: [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]. When I try to run tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(140, 140, 3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet') 
I get an error mentioning this:

Comment: WARNING:tensorflow:`input_shape` is undefined or non-square, or `rows` is not in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]. Weights for input shape (224, 224) will be loaded as the default.